# getting error while trying to get String value from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting an error while trying to access the string AFH(currencyId). The error I am getting is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Continents' of undefined"
[image: JSON]

Here is how I am trying to access the string.

(1) After I made ajax request to the endpoint of the Json file, I stored the info(data) under variable named data when the ajax request is success.

(2) This is where the error comes from:

```
console.log(data.Continents[0].Countries[0].CurrencyId)
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am missing?

Comment: Can you add the code to the question?

Comment: number two is the actual line code that is causing error. assume "data"  represents the json data as shown on the pic.

Comment: Oh didn't see that!

Comment: sry my bad. On my actual code the space doesnt exist'

Comment: Does `console.log(data.Continents[0].Countries[0])` exist?

Comment: That error message seems to imply that `data` is undefined. What happens when you `console.log(data)` does it return the object like you expect?

Comment: @Jon post the full code, I data is undefined, you're not saving the JSON into a variable.

Comment: If I had to guess I think your `console.log(data)` is being called outside of your ajax success callback, but I would need to see your code to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

You have a space between `Countries` and `[0]`

```
console.log(data.Continents[0].Countries [0].CurrencyId)
```

should be

```
console.log(data.Continents[0].Countries[0].CurrencyId)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, that is not the case. For some reson, I am not able to get rid of the space here on stackoverflow

Comment: Apparently this was a typo in the question.

Comment: It isnt that, it actually works with the space (tested it in the dev tools a minute ago)

Comment: I am trying, yet it is not going away

Answer (score 1):

The most likely culprit is the A of AJAX.  Assuming that your code looks something like this (using jQuery for brevity):

```
var data;
$.get('/endpoint.json', function(response) {
  data = response;
});
console.log(data.Continents[0].Countries[0].CurrencyId);
```

In this simple example, the data variable is being defined but only after the AJAX request completes however because the AJAX request is made asynchronously, the `console.log()` is executed immediately (before the data variable is actually defined).  This can seem counter intuitive because by the time you move the cursor down to the JS Console the `data` variable will have been defined and then can be logged.  The obvious solution to this issue is to move your console.log inside your success callback or define a separate function that uses your data and call it from the ajax success callback.

Comment: it turns out that the url does not have .json extension. Does that make a difference to how I should approach the problem?

Comment: There can be a related issue that jQuery can hide.  If the server is not expressly sending a `content-type` header with the value `application/json`(http://stackoverflow.com/a/477819/16959) then jQuery will look at the URL to guess if the result should be parsed as JSON.  You can override this by passing a datatype to `jQuery.get()` (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or by parsing the response with vanilla JavaScript using `JSON.parse(data)` however this would not explain your `undefined` `data` issue as in that case `data` would be a `String` (though still lacking a `Continents` property)

Comment: Finally, you are on the right track when it comes to the error I am getting

Answer (score 0):

You need to post more of the code. Sure `console.log(data.Continents[0].Countries[0].CurrencyId)` might be throwing the actual error, but it is most likely because previous lines are not doing what they're supposed to. Most likely your code to do the ajax request isn't functioning properly, so `data` isn't actually being filled with the JSON and is being left as `undefined` which would throw that error.